# Eye tracking - estimating face position

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, opticalflow, eye-tracking

I want to create an eye-tracker using EmguCV. I came across the problem of calculating the face position, which I need to get in order to correctly estimate the gaze of a person. I wanted to use the Haar cascade to detect face and then, using the optical flow method, track some face features. The problem is what to do next.

How can I project tracked 2D points to the 3D to extract the rotation matrix? I heard about the POSIT algorithm but to use it I need a 3D face model. Is there a method to create a face model automatically during the initialization of a program?

Comment: sounds like you are new to the field. which probably means you will struggle with this. for example, opencv will not give you an accurate face position (what would that even be!) and optical flow likely won't help you wit finding or tracking eyes. why not use an existing implementation of an eye tracker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle I found a solution. In short I short I found some good features to track and basing on them I created sinusoidal face model. This model was used within POSIT algorithm to compute rotation matrix and translation vector. To project 2D point into 3D model I used a pinhole camera model.